# Angular 11: Wrong Typecheck for UnitTest Spy on HttpClient.get()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-httpclient, angular11

When unit testing Angular's HttpClient.get(...) function, it seems that TypeScript cannot check types correctly when spying on HttpClient.get(...) with given responseType.

This error appeared after upgrading to Angular 11.

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
  }).compileComponents();
});

it('should check HttpClient.get()', () => {
  const http = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
  const httpGetSpy = spyOn(http, 'get').and.returnValue(of('Test result.'));
  http.get('/test/url', { responseType: 'text' });
  
  expect(httpGetSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    '/test/url',
    { responseType: 'text'}
    // ^^^ Error:
    // "Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json" | undefined'.
  );
});
```

Besides the simple reproducer above here is a more reasonable example as it appears in my production code:

```js
// example.service.ts
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ExampleService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  doSomething(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('/some/url', { responseType: 'text' });
  }
}

// example.service.spec.ts
describe('ExampleService', () => {
  let service: ExampleService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(ExampleService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    const http = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    const httpGetSpy = spyOn(http, 'get').and.returnValue(of('Test result.'));
    service.doSomething().subscribe();
    expect(httpGetSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/some/url', { responseType: 'text' });
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the HttpClientTestingModule?

Comment: I am using the HttClientTestingModule. I should have added the beforeEach where I inititialize the TestBed. Sorry for that.

Comment: I know you are asking a question about type checking but I am just baffled here. You created a problem by writing an absolutely pointless test. There is no reason to test HttpClient - the Angular team has already done that. Also, when testing api services that use HttpClient you need to use HttpClientTestingModule - that is what it is designed for and you won't get these errors.

Comment: So, first of all, I am Using the HttpClientTestingModule. I added the missing before each. Hopefully, that is more clear now.

Comment: And, of course, you are right. The test as I wrote it above is pointless. I wrote it like that to have a minimal example to show the error I am facing. In my app I am testing a service function that uses the HttpClient internally and calls its get method among other things. So I added a more reasonable example to show my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the reason you are getting this error is because Angular is moving in the direction of stronger type checking. This will allow for better build optimizations. Angular 11 fixed a lot of 'lose' typing's. You need to add a type to the spy you created.

```
const httpGetSpy: jasmine.Spy<(arg0: string, {}) => Observable<string>> = spyOn(http, 'get').and.returnValue(of('Test result.'));
```

or you can just make it simple and do this

```
const httpGetSpy: jasmine.Spy<any> = spyOn(http, 'get').and.returnValue(of('Test result.'));
```

Comment: I just use `const httpGetSpy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(httpClient, 'get').and.returnValue(of(document));` now which is technically the same as your second proposal. That works great. It seems that TypeScript does not infer the correct type for the `get` function, since it has some overloads depending on the `responseType` property in the options parameter.

Thank you @AndrewAlderson for your support. 